# Compare two arrays with unordered items in php

Tags: php, arrays

H have an array with year,month,day,hour,minute,second (I do not know which item in array is year,month,etc.. it's unordered)
but I have a fixed date format like: yy-mm-dd-h-m-s that can help me.

I wrote this code and I tried underestand true item.

```
function ($date,$format)
{
$year = $month = $day = $hour = $minute = $second = 0;    

$format = 'yy-mm-dd-h-m-s'; //string
$date   = (1998,12,31,23,44,49) ; // an array

$format = explode("-",$format);
$date = explode("-",$date);

$date = array_filter(array_unique($date));
$format = array_filter(array_unique($format));

for($i=0;$i<6;$i++)
{
    if($format[$i] == 'yy') $year = $date[$i];
    elseif($format[$i] == 'mm') $month = $date[$i];
    elseif($format[$i] == 'dd') $day = $date[$i];
    elseif($format[$i] == 'h') $hour = $date[$i];
    elseif($format[$i] == 'm') $minute = $date[$i];
    elseif($format[$i] == 's') $second = $date[$i];     
}
echo $year.$month.$day;
```

}

But I got this error:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in
>   /home/admin/domains/example.com/public_html/admin/lib/core.php on line
>   2058 Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in
>   /home/admin/domains/example.com/public_html/admin/lib/core.php on line
>   2059 Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in
>   /home/admin/domains/example.com/public_html/admin/lib/core.php on line
>   2060 Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in
>   /home/admin/domains/example.com/public_html/admin/lib/core.php on line
>   2061 Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in

Can somebody say my problem?

Comment: So you have 1 array with one element e.g. `1998-12-31-23-44-49` and another array  with one element with the same data, but in different order? And you want to check if they are the same ?

Comment: `$date = (1998-12-31-23-44-49);` doesn't look like array syntax to me. it's an integer.

Comment: @Alexander your right but it's an array

Comment: and what's `array_filter` supposed to achieve if you're not providing a callback?

Comment: @Rizier123 please check my algorithm...I want to work my algorithm...I convert string ($format) to an array with 6 items...also I have another array with 6 items...so why I can not call them?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is your array syntax. You either need to use array(), or enclose the items in square brackets [].